# Retrofit, не получается увеличить время ожидания

Tags: java

Использую библиотеку Retrofit, когда медленный интернет, то при отправке фотографий на сервер возникает ошибка time out. Попробовал таким способом увеличить время ожидания, но все равно время ожидания по умолчанию 10 сек. Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.
Вот мой код:

```
 public class RestClient {
   private UploadService  uploadService;
   private String URL ="http://10.0.2.2:7899/api/";
    public RestClient(){
            Gson localGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.uploadService = ((UploadService) new  RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setEndpoint(URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(localGson))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                         if (URL.contains("10.0.2.2")) {
                         requestFacade.addHeader("Host", "localhost");                           
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build().create(UploadService.class));
    }

    public UploadService getService()
    {
        Log.e("ServiceName", this.uploadService.toString());
        return this.uploadService;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточните пожалуйста версию okhttp. там с 3.0 фича новая - нужно через билдер делать.

т.е. в вашем случае будет:

```
public class RestClient {
   private UploadService  uploadService;
   private String URL ="http://10.0.2.2:7899/api/";
    public RestClient(){
            Gson localGson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                           .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                           .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                           .build();
        this.uploadService = ((UploadService) new  RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
                .setEndpoint(URL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(localGson))
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
                         if (URL.contains("10.0.2.2")) {
                         requestFacade.addHeader("Host", "localhost");                           
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build().create(UploadService.class));
    }

    public UploadService getService()
    {
        Log.e("ServiceName", this.uploadService.toString());
        return this.uploadService;
    }

}
```

подробней можно глянуть [тут](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts)

Comment: Версия OkHttp 2.6.0.

Comment: @iS_Tom а версия ретрофита?

Comment: ретрофит версии 1.9.0

Comment: @iS_Tom может звучать глупо, но попробуйте понизить версию okHttp до 2.5.0

Comment: понизил версию okhttp до 2.5.0, использовав свой код. По прежнему тайм аут по дефолту. Я вот думаю, если повысить версию okHttp до 3.2.0 и попробовать ваш код, то по идее должно сработать?

Comment: @iS_Tom есть только один путь это проверить)

Comment: столкнулся с такой ошибкой в этой строке: ".setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))". Как решить проблему с доступом  Error:(62, 28) error: cannot access OkHttpClient
class file for com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient not found

Comment: @iS_Tom предполагаю что несовместимость старой версий ретрофита и okHttp :(

Comment: обновил ретрофит до новой версии 2.0.2. Ошибка с доступом осталась :(

Comment: @iS_Tom сейчас проверил, у меня в проекте лежит retrofit 1.9.0 и okHttp 2.5.0 и вроде как все в порядке. видимо, не смогу помочь. у меня точно такая же нога, и она не болит)

Comment: добавил это : " compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit1-okhttp3-client:1.0.2' ", и использовал ваш пример с okHttp3, и изменил строку, где была ошибка с доступом на эту : " .setClient(new Ok3Client(okHttpClient)) " и все заработало.